# Getting RGB color value, using user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for help with my homework.

I need to write a program which will calculate RGB color value in defined ranges using list and user input.
User is inputting value from 0-100 % and program return valid RGB color value.
I'm totally green even don't know how to begin...

```
colour0percent = [0,255,0]
colour50percent = [255,128,0]
colour100percent = [255,0,0]
percentage = int(input("Input: "))
colour = []
print(percentage, colour)
```

I want to receive output:

```
Input: 50
50, [255,128,0]

Input: 33
33, [168,171,0]
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: As posed, this question makes no sense. The user input is 0-100% of What? Red,Green,Blue, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the formula in mathematics and then implement it. from the little examples that you have mentioned we can't realize the problem but this answer may point you some good directions:

```
percentage = int(input("Input: "))
r = 255 if percentage >= 50 else int((percentage/50)*255)
g = 255 - 255*percentage/100
b = 0
color = [r, g, b]
print(percentage, color)
```

Comment: green will be a float.

Comment: it's just an inspiration and you can cast it to int by wrapping it with `int()`

Comment: I'm keenly aware of that. I was attempting to inspire you to correct it, given that it is now an accepted answer.